# Getting "module not defined" error when using Gulp to run karma tests

Tags: angularjs, gulp, karma-runner

My team is working on moving from Grunt to Gulp. I have a Grunt test task that works fine, but when I try to run the tests (using gulp-karma) I get an error that says "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module"

I Googled and found a lot of posts saying to check the location of my angular-mocks.js file, and it's in the correct space (my Grunt task for the same code *does* work).

To verify that it wasn't something weird in my code a spun up a new yo angular app and was able to replicate the error.

My guess is that I'm missing a configuration value or a step or something. Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share any of your code? My hunch is that if you are running your tests through Gulp using yeoman gulp generator, you haven't loaded your files to unit-test.js. This is my only speculation without seeing code.

Comment: @mcranston18 Sure, I can share whatever you need to see from the empty project I created. What do you need?

Comment: Do you have a link to a GitHub repo that can reproduce the issue?

Comment: @JayHarris Yeah, https://github.com/JamesBender/GulpTest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are running `gulp tests`, gulp-karma is looking for files within `gulpfile.js`, not `karma.conf.js` as you have defined. Remember, when you return `gulp.src(tests)`, you are passing in the array of files needed for the tests to pass.

To fix your problem, in your `gulpfile.js`, update your `tests` array to include your bower files, app files, and test files:

```
var tests = [
  'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
  'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
  'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
  'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
  'bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
  'app/scripts/app.js',
  'app/scripts/**/*.js',
  'test/mock/**/*.js',
  'test/spec/**/*.js'
];
```

You can delete the `files` array in `karma.conf.js` as they are not needed.

(p.s. I also made a reference to app.js as `app/scripts/**/*.js` would not have matched app.js which needs to be loaded in first)

Comment: This is also noted in [gulp-karma#27](https://github.com/lazd/gulp-karma/issues/27) and is one of the primary issues of `gulp-karma`. They are working on potential resolutions.

Comment: BTW, If you wanted your files defined in the karma.conf.js, you could just pass in an empty array to gulp.src (i.e. `return gulp.src([])` )

Answer (score 6):

The answer by @mcranston18 will absolutely work. But as an alternative option, `gulp-karma` is currently an unnecessary plugin. Part of the advantage of `gulp` is that you don't have to use a plugin for everything under the sun. Instead, you can wire into `karma` directly.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var karma = require('karma').server;

gulp.task('tests', function(done) {
  return karma.start({
      configFile: __dirname + '/test/karma.conf.js',
      singleRun: true
    }, done);
});
```

Comment: Never thought of this & it does seem like a preferable solution. It would be nice if the generator used this approach.

Comment: I get the following error: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'start'

Comment: Did you install `karma` through NPM?